# JavaScript Form Submit Assistance

Tags: javascript, forms, post, if-statement

I'm trying to get my code to alert me if anything is not filled in, checked, or selected before it submits. I'm also having trouble getting it to alert me if a month or day isn't selected. Any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Field Trip Consent Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validates() { 
var radioChecked = false;

for(var i=0; i< document.form1.permission.length; i++) {
if(document.form1.permission[i].checked) {
      radioChecked = true;          
    }
}
if(radioChecked == false) {      
    alert("Please chose permission Status");
    return false;          
} 
if(document.form1.txtParent.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in the textbox");    
    return false;            
}
if(document.form1.destination.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in the textbox");   
    return false;            
}    
return true;
}

function validates1(){
var moMonth = document.getElementById("getMonth").value;
var moDay = document.getElementById("day").value;

if(moMonth == "") { 
    alert("Please select a Month"); 
    return false; 
}   
if(moDay == "") { 
    alert("Please select a Day"); 
    return false;
}   
return true;        
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Field Trip Consent Form</h1>

<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validates(); validates1()" method="post" 
action="http://legacy.jefferson.kctcs.edu/users/mark.prather/formhandler.asp"> 

<form>

<h2>Description of Trip</h2>
<p>Destination &nbsp;

<input type="text" name="destination" SIZE="50" /></p>
<p>Date of Trip &nbsp;
<select name="month" id='getMonth'>
<option selected value="Month">Month
<option value="Jan">Jan
<option value="Feb">Feb
<option value="Mar">Mar
<option value="Apr">Apr
<option value="May">May
<option value="Jun">Jun
<option value="Jul">Jul
<option value="Aug">Aug
<option value="Sep">Sep
<option value="Oct">Oct
<option value="Nov">Nov
<option value="Dec">Dec
</select>
<select name="day">
<option selected value="Day">Day
<option value="01">01
<option value="02">02
<option value="03">03
<option value="04">04
<option value="05">05
<option value="06">06
<option value="07">07
<option value="08">08
<option value="09">09
<option value="10">10
<option value="11">11
<option value="12">12
<option value="13">13
<option value="14">14
<option value="15">15
<option value="16">16
<option value="17">17
<option value="18">18
<option value="19">19
<option value="20">20
<option value="21">21
<option value="22">22
<option value="23">23
<option value="24">24
<option value="25">25
<option value="26">26
<option value="27">27
<option value="28">28
<option value="29">29
<option value="30">30
<option value="31">31
</select>

<select name="year">
<option selected value="2012">2012
<option value="2013">2013
<option value="2014">2014
<option value="2015">2015
</select>


<h2>Parental Information</h2>
<p>Mother's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p>Mother's Work Phone &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p>Father's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p>Father's Work Phone &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="permission" value="yes" /> Permission is Granted &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="permission" value="no" /> Permission is NOT Granted &nbsp;</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit This Data" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="reset" /></p> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm stuck in a loop from my first function. Even after inputting data into the form it alerts me that I haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Field Trip Consent Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validates() { 
var radioChecked = false;

for(var i=0; i< document.form1.permission.length; i++) {
if(document.form1.permission[i].checked) {
      radioChecked = true;          
    }
}
if(radioChecked == false) {      
    alert("Please chose permission Status");
    return false;          
} 
if(document.form1.txtParent.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in the textbox");    
    return false;            
}
if(document.form1.destination.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in the destination box");   
    return false;            
}    
return true;
}
function validates1(){
var m = document.getElementById("getMonth");
var moMonth = m.options[m.selectedIndex].value;
var d = document.getElementById("day");
var moDay = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;

if(moMonth == "Month") { 
    alert("Please select a Month"); 
    return false; 
}   
if(moDay == "Day") { 
    alert("Please select a Day"); 
    return false;
}   
return true;        
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Field Trip Consent Form</h1>

<form name="form1" onsubmit="validates(),validates1();" method="post" action="/test.php"> 
<h2>Description of Trip</h2>
<p>Destination &nbsp;

<input type="text" name="destination" SIZE="50" /></p>
<p>Date of Trip &nbsp;
<select name="month" id="getMonth">
<option selected value="Month">Month</option>
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
<option value="Mar">Mar</option>
<option value="Apr">Apr</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">Jun</option>
<option value="Jul">Jul</option>
<option value="Aug">Aug</option>
<option value="Sep">Sep</option>
<option value="Oct">Oct</option>
<option value="Nov">Nov</option>
<option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select>
<select name="day" id="day">
<option selected value="Day">Day
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="year">
<option selected value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>


<h2>Parental Information</h2>
<p>Mother's Name &nbsp;
<input type="text" name="txtParent" size="20" /></p>

<p><input type="radio" name="permission" value="yes" /> Permission is Granted &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="permission" value="no" /> Permission is NOT Granted &nbsp;</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit This Data" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="reset" /></p> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Always use

```
var m = document.getElementById("getMonth");
var moMonth = m.options[m.selectedIndex].value;
var d = document.getElementById("day");
var moDay = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
```

like this for select options

Use this.. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onsubmit="return validates(); validates1()"
```

to:

```
onsubmit="return (validates() || validates1())"
```

Your code returns immediately after calling `validates()`, so it never calls `validates1()`. This code first calls `validates()`. If it returns `false`, that gets returned as the result (so the form is not submitted). Otherwise, it then calls `validates1()` and returns its result.